# Resizing images in jquery not working on all images

Tags: jquery

I want it to scale all instances of the `td img.standingslogo` but it's not working properly

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ze5ebnw7/13/

```
$(window).load(function(){
    image = []
    $('td img.standingslogo').each(function() {
        imageWidth = $(this).width();
        image[$(this).index()] = imageWidth;
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('td img.standingslogo').hide();
        $('td img.standingslogo').each(function() {
            tdWidth = $(this).parent().width();
            imgWidth = image[$(this).index()];
            if (imgWidth>=tdWidth) {$(this).css({width:tdWidth});} else {$(this).css({width:imgWidth});}
            $(this).show();
        });
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: It's not clear from that jsfiddle what problem you're experiencing. What is happening, and what do you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working now

```
$(window).load(function(){
image = [];
i=0;
$('.standingslogo').each(function() {
    imageWidth = $(this).width();
    image[i] = imageWidth;
    i++
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.standingslogo').hide();
    i=0;
    $('.standingslogo').each(function() {
        tdWidth = $(this).parent().width();
        imgWidth = image[i];
        if (imgWidth>=tdWidth) {$(this).css({width:tdWidth});} else {$(this).css({width:imgWidth});}
        $(this).show();
        i++
    });
}).resize();

});
```